# Search table with select2 dropdowns in one column

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am creating a table with one column consisting of select2 dropdowns. Refer fig below : [image]

HTML code looks like this :

```
<table class="table table-hover table-borderless" id="tabpro">
<tbody class="list">
  <tr class="t-row">
     <td class="name" style="width: 370px;padding-left:50px;">
        <h5>BR-2C-4567</h5>
     </td>
     <td class="driver-name">
        <form class="edit_truck" id="edit_truck_1" action="/trucker/trucks/1/update_driver.1" accept-charset="UTF-8" method="post">
           <input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="&#x2713;" /><input type="hidden" name="_method" value="put" /><input type="hidden" name="authenticity_token" value="c113UiPfI8Jk72/iivm9qJhIys8udhgaynEJUaMHjkTqpZIm+9R1VYbe1QN5+0jrGReMOb2E9w75fsvI37Mh/w==" />
           <span class="select2box">
              <select class="select-example" name="truck[driver_id]" id="truck_driver_id">
                 <option value="">No drivers selected</option>
                 <option value="1">Shubham</option>
                 <option selected="selected" value="2">XYZ</option>
              </select>
           </span>
           <input type="submit" name="commit" value="Update Driver" class="btn btn-default" />
        </form>
     </td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="t-row">
     <td class="name" style="width: 370px;padding-left:50px;">
        <h5>sasadga</h5>
     </td>
     <td class="driver-name">
        <form class="edit_truck" id="edit_truck_2" action="/trucker/trucks/2/update_driver.2" accept-charset="UTF-8" method="post">
           <input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="&#x2713;" /><input type="hidden" name="_method" value="put" /><input type="hidden" name="authenticity_token" value="yy8hpB+cBT2bcyyYBn+ZmLHUT+nBVGg0QPwytmtZ8QVS18TQx5dTqnlClnn1fWzbMIsJH1KmhyBz8/AvF+1evg==" />
           <span class="select2box">
              <select class="select-example" name="truck[driver_id]" id="truck_driver_id">
                 <option value="">No drivers selected</option>
                 <option selected="selected" value="1">Shubham</option>
                 <option value="2">XYZ</option>
              </select>
           </span>
           <input type="submit" name="commit" value="Update Driver" class="btn btn-default" />
        </form>
     </td>
  </tr>
  .... 
 </table>
```

I'm able to search Vehicles using listjs plugin. But how to search drivers ?
I tried using this code but it doesn't work.(I'm javascript, jQuery beginner).

```
$('.searchDriver').keyup(function(){
      var srchTerm = $(this).val(),
          rows = $('tbody.list').find('tr'),
          opt = $('.select2box').find('select option:selected');

      if (srchTerm.length > 0) {
          rows.stop().hide();
          if($('.select2box').find('select option:selected').text().indexOf('x') == -1){
            opt.closest('tr').stop().show();
          }
      }else {
            rows.stop().show();
        }  
    });
```

Please share a working example/ guide me to accomplish this task.

Comment: I do not have an answer, but phrases like "doesn't work" are very ambiguous. What is the actual result of the code above? Please [update your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/33932733/edit) to include any error messages from your javascript console.

Comment: No error in console. Nothing happens. The table remains unaltered.